# Wordlist generator for known words in passphrase

Tags: passwords

Is there any well-known solution to generate wordlists using (for lack of a better term) wordsets instead of charsets?

I know parts of my old password, but I can't remember the exact order. After much searching, the most popular options only seem to offer static patterns using single-character charsets. What I'm looking for is a tool that allows mangling with the order (or at least make optional) known parts of the passphrase.

Example:

I know my password starts with `Aword`, followed by a special character. I also know `Bword` and `Cword` is in the password, and some special chars are in between. I don't know if `Cword` or `Bword` comes first. Also, `Dword` might be included *somewhere*, with or without special chars surrounding it, too.

Wordlist (assuming special chars is always "+"):

```
Aword+Bword+Cword
Aword+Cword+Bword
Aword+Bword+Cword+Dword
Aword+Cword+Bword+Dword
Aword+Bword+Dword+Cword
Aword+Cword+Dword+Bword
Aword+Dword+Bword+Cword
Aword+Dword+Cword+Bword
Aword+Bword+CwordDword
Aword+Cword+BwordDword
Aword+BwordDword+Cword
Aword+CwordDword+Bword
Aword+DwordBword+Cword
Aword+DwordCword+Bword
```

While not accurate/perfect, I know `bash` expansion could do that:

```
echo Aword+{,Bword,Cword,Dword}{,+}[,Bword,Cword,Dword}{,+}{,Bword,Cword,Dword}
```

This also outputs false candidates like `Aword+BwordBwordBword`, but this could be filtered out, I assume. My problem with this approach is: Bash eats all my RAM, then dies.

I'm happy with too many / false candidates being generated as well as huge output files, so as long as the generating program doesn't crash.

Comment: this looks like a simple job for a scripting language like python

Comment: Unfortunately, this is either a programming question or a request for a tool. Both are off-topic here, but Stack Overflow  migth be able to handle the programming question.

Answer (score 2):

Using custom rules within john-the-ripper `John` you can write variations of the password. [Using John The Ripper to create variations of a known password.](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/26354045/Using-John-The-Ripper-to-create-variations-of-a-known-password.html)

Comment: This is a link-only answer. Can you include the relevant parts of the link in your answer?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any well-known solution to generate wordlists using (for lack of a better term) wordsets instead of charsets?

take a look at code like this:

https://github.com/Mebus/cupp

You could change this in terms of what you need or rewrite it on your own with features you want.